# Should I Inform or ask for Approval when coming office one hour late?

Tags: communication, manager

Do you usually ask for approval or just inform manager if you are going to be late on a certain day to office?

I joined new company and sent email to my manager that I will be one hour late as I have to go to SSN office two days in Advance but he still called me on my mobile asking why am I still not in office? I told him I sent email two days ago about this and he said "ok" and he sounded very disappointed saying we have a defect and we need you to fix immediately.

I have family and I may need to go for doctor appointments and things like this. How do I avoid these situations in the future?

Comment: How you should handle taking time off is heavily company-dependent. If your boss isn't happy with you taking an hour off here and there, you'll need to take leave for that. Or maybe they're fine with it if you *get permission* first, or if you inform them in a different way (plenty of people are overwhelmed by the number of emails they get), but you'll need to ask them.

Comment: VTC, every company/group has a different attitude towards this, from absences aren't allowed to they require official dispensation to they require verbal manager pre-approval to you just need to inform him to you just do it and don't even bother telling anyone.  Even reading between the lines and narrowing this down to a coding job in the US, there's no single answer.

Comment: One hour "extra" pay or "lost" work is seldom worth formal accounting. Policies aside, what most bosses really care about in this regard is that you don't make them look bad or leave them guessing as to your whereabouts, or miss meetings/customers/events.

Answer (score 1):

In that kind of situation, it is not about *what you are asking*, but *the way you are asking*.

What I usually do in similar situations:

1. **I ask for permission**, but indirectly making it clear that it is very important (my child is really sick, I need an appointment to the immigration office for my visa, etc.)
2. **I always and immediately say that I will compensate the lost time**. That's very important to say it before being asking to.
3. **I try to do it only when it is really necessary**. Don't lie when doing #1, and try not to be *the guy that always go off the limits*.
4. **Be very specific and direct**, and remind your manager the day before: the worst thing for him would be to spend too much time or having to worried about your case.

An other advice: **it is even more easy when you are an efficient employee**. If they know that you will actually do the work and maybe over compensate the lost hours, they will trust you: be more than a number, and they won't treat you as a number.

If they refuse everything, then it is an other problem. In my opinion, sick child is always more important than a weekly team meeting. If my company disagrees, then I need to find an other one...

Answer (score 1):

> Do you usually ask for approval or just inform manager if you are
>   going to be late on a certain day to office?

Where I worked, the standard procedure was to inform the manager. No need to ask permission.

> I have family and I may need to go for doctor appointments and things
>   like this. How do I avoid these situations in the future?

You avoid awkwardness by asking your bosses how they would prefer to be notified, and then following the required procedure.

Communication is key. Guessing can cause problems.